# Creating an updating time series using a live download into excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, finance, yahoo-finance, vba

```
Sub GetData()

Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim qurl As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

Range("C7").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
i = 7
qurl = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + Cells(i, 1)
i = i + 1
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    qurl = qurl + "+" + Cells(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
Wend
qurl = qurl + "&f=" + Range("C2")
Range("c1") = qurl
QueryQuote:
             With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, 
Destination:=DataSheet.Range("C7"))
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                .SaveData = True
            End With

j = Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row

For k = 7 To j

Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc. Common Stoc", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc. Common St", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc. Co St", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc. Co", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc. (The)", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc. Com", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Inc.", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Incorporated C", "")
Cells(k, "C").Value = Replace(Cells(k, "C").Value, ", Incorporated", "")

Next

            Range("C7").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C7"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False


'turn calculation back on
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Range("C7:H2000").Select
    'Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess,     _
    '    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 25
    Rows("7:2000").RowHeight = 16
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 8.5

Call test

End Sub

Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "GetData"
End Sub
```

I have this adapted code to download stock prices from Yahoo finance. What I'd like to do is add values to a graph every time the data refreshes in order to build a time series. Is there an easy way to copy each price value (20 stocks) into a separate sheet each time the cell refreshes with a new price and then plot them onto a graph?

Comment: Yes, there are easy ways to do that. What have you tried so far to achieve that goal? Your code is just something that runs every ten seconds and refreshes the data table...

Comment: @RikSportel haven't really tried anything to any degree of success so far, I've never done something like this so am not sure where I'd start!

Comment: Start by breaking the problem down into little steps. You already have the data, so what you want to do is: 1. Get the range with data. 2. Copy-paste it into another sheet in the range that your chart will use (or just assign the values to that range) 3. Make sure the chart takes the new column/row into account in the series (so either include a big enough range, or change the chart range in the script). 
Thing is: Start coding. When you get stuck, let us know what the exact problem is. StackOverflow is not a free coding service. "Can someone help me" is not considered a question here.